# The Sum of this finite series

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, summation

How do I calculate the sum of this finite series using a mathematical formula? I can derive the series, but I am not sure how to show mathematically that the sum is equal to approximately 2365.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{365}\frac{365}n$$

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JITE8.jpg

Comment: I don't think there's a better way to evaluate that series exactly than just adding everything up.

Comment: What's the question? $\sum_{n=1}^{365} \frac 1n \approx 6.48$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: If you guys don't mind, check the link

Comment: @lulu my question is for 365/n

Comment: $\sum \frac {365}n = 365*\sum \frac 1n$ so if lulu is correct and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{365} \frac 1n \approx 6.48$ then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{365} \frac {365}n \approx 365*6.48$.  So far as I know the only way to figure $\sum\limits_{n=1}^k \frac 1n$ is to do them.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: Ok.  So multiply by $365$.

Comment: There isn't an easy way to compute the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).  Of course there are estimates.  But if you want the value, you have to dig down and compute it.

Comment: So there is no formula for the sum of a harmonic series? Like there is for a geometric series for example.